# Eclipse 2020 language server for JS is showing error on thymeleaf to javascript variables

Tags: javascript, spring, eclipse, thymeleaf

After upgrade from Eclipse 2019 to Eclipse 2020-03 I'm getting Markers: 'Language Server Error' on codes of thymeleaf to javascript variables. I still can run the code but the problem is these annoying messages.

I've tried to disable Eclipse language server preferences but nothing change.

For example, in a thymeleaf HTML file:

```
<script th:inline="javascript"> 
  // thymeleaf to javascript variables
  var txSiglaUsina = [[${usina.txSigla}]];
  var idUsina = [[${usina.id}]];
  var cfgsVazaoSanitariaRef = [[${vazaoSanitariaRef}]];
  var contextPath = [[@{/}]];
  var blHoraCheia = false;  
</script>
```

I got this Eclipse Markers errors:
 [image: Eclipse Markers]

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is disabling Eclipse Language Server on: Windows > Preferences > Language Server.

As I wrote above I've tried that but nothing change, only after editing and saving the file the erros Markers finally disapear.

Comment: Thanks, I used Windows > Preferences > Language Servers      and then unselected HTML Language Server (VSCode)